# rsync over ssh triggers a "Cannot execute command-line and remote command" error

Tags: ssh, rsync, remotecommand

I want to copy files using `rsync` over ssh, but a "Cannot execute command-line and remote command." is raised, meanwhile it works fine with `scp`.

Command : `rsync -ravh folder XXX:folder`

My ssh config is configured as follows :

```
Host XXX
  Hostname YY
  User user
  RequestTTY yes
  RemoteCommand bash --init-file ~/.bashrc
```

I noticed that by removing the `RemoteCommand` option, rsync does the job.

How could I manage to make rsync work while using my current ssh host config ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Option: define a separate Host (e.g. `XXX.ssh`) in `~/.ssh/config` and use it in your `rsync` command

```
Host XXX XXX.ssh
  Hostname YY
  User user

Host XXX
  RequestTTY yes
  RemoteCommand bash --init-file ~/.bashrc
```

```bash
$ rsync -ravh folder XXX.ssh:folder
```

2. Option: Override `RemoteCommand` directive with `-e|--rsh` rsync option

```bash
$ rsync -ravh folder -e "ssh -o RemoteCommand=none" XXX:folder
```